# How to insert records from a database into another database table?

Tags: mysql

I have two `databases` and I want to `insert` the results of a `query` from the first `database` into another table in the second `database`. How to do that using MySQL ?

Comment: are the two databases on the same server?

Comment: yes they are on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both databases are on same system you may try something like, In the below example data is migrated from oldDatabase table1 to newDatabase table1. This is the basic example, you can do your variation of query with it.

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (column1, column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Insert into target-database.target-table(col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from source-database.source-table
```

Use the above format.

Comment: if the databases are on the same server, then this works. Are they?

Comment: yes they are on the same server as confirmed by questioner @pheromix

Answer (score 1):

If you have two databases db1 and db2.
If you want the table to have the same structure use.

```
CREATE TABLE db2.tableA LIKE db1.tableA;
```

To copy the data use,

```
INSERT INTO db2.tableA SELECT * FROM db1.tableA;
```

If the tables are different and you only want to copy the data, specify the columns. The key thing to consider is the column datatype and size.

```
INSERT INTO db2.tableA(col1,col2) (SELECT col1,col2 FROM db1.tableA);
```